# Why does %>% not work with apply()?

Tags: r, magrittr

Consider the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(Total = c(3450, 1728, 122, 5300), 
                   A1 = c(1092, 497, 4, 1593), 
                   A2 = c(596, 156, 29, 781), 
                   A3 = c(801, 417, 36, 1254), 
                   A4 = c(107, 11, 0, 118), 
                   A5 = c(614, 217, 21, 852), 
                   A6 = c(132, 47, 0, 179), 
                   A7 = c(108, 383, 32, 523)), 
              .Names = c("Total", paste0("A", 1:7)), 
              row.names = c(paste0("B", 1:3), "Total"), 
              class = "data.frame")

      Total   A1  A2   A3  A4  A5  A6  A7
B1     3450 1092 596  801 107 614 132 108
B2     1728  497 156  417  11 217  47 383
B3      122    4  29   36   0  21   0  32
Total  5300 1593 781 1254 118 852 179 523
```

The problem is as follows: letting the row `Total` be the denominator, calculate the percentage that each cell in the same column is of the row `Total`.

In this case, I would do

```
df_names <- rownames(df)

df2 <- apply(
  round(
    sweep(df, 
          STATS = as.matrix(df[rownames(df) == "Total",]),
          MARGIN = 2,
          FUN = "/") * 100,
    digits = 2),
  MARGIN = 2,
  FUN = paste0,
  "%")

rownames(df2) <- df_names
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)

       Total     A1     A2     A3     A4     A5     A6     A7
B1    65.09% 68.55% 76.31% 63.88% 90.68% 72.07% 73.74% 20.65%
B2     32.6%  31.2% 19.97% 33.25%  9.32% 25.47% 26.26% 73.23%
B3      2.3%  0.25%  3.71%  2.87%     0%  2.46%     0%  6.12%
Total   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%
```

**but**, although this works, I prefer using `%>%`:

```
df3 <- sweep(df, 
             STATS = as.matrix(df[rownames(df) == "Total",]),
             MARGIN = 2,
             FUN = "/") * 100 %>%
       round(digits = 2) %>%
       apply(., MARGIN = 2, FUN = paste0, "%")

Error in apply(., MARGIN = 2, FUN = paste0, "%") : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Why does the method above using `%>%` not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the trailing numeric 100 and how it enter the pipe. Surround with `()` and apply will work fine, or for a less involved solution:

```
(sweep(df, 
      STATS = as.matrix(df[rownames(df) == "Total",]),
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = "/") * 100) %>% round(digits = 2) %>%
    mutate_all(function(x)sprintf('%s%%', x))

   Total     A1     A2     A3     A4     A5     A6     A7
1 65.09% 68.55% 76.31% 63.88% 90.68% 72.07% 73.74% 20.65%
2  32.6%  31.2% 19.97% 33.25%  9.32% 25.47% 26.26% 73.23%
3   2.3%  0.25%  3.71%  2.87%     0%  2.46%     0%  6.12%
4   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%
```

## Edit to show a little about why..

The `%>%` takes two args, and generates an environment. The arguments are `lhs` and `rhs` with left-hand-side being input values

```
sweep(df, 
      STATS = as.matrix(df[rownames(df) == "Total",]),
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = "/") * 100 %>% print

[1] 100
           Total          A1         A2         A3         A4         A5        A6         A7
B1     65.094340  68.5499058  76.312420  63.875598  90.677966  72.065728  73.74302  20.650096
B2     32.603774  31.1989956  19.974392  33.253589   9.322034  25.469484  26.25698  73.231358
B3      2.301887   0.2510986   3.713188   2.870813   0.000000   2.464789   0.00000   6.118547
Total 100.000000 100.0000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.00000 100.000000
```

### Notice the [1] 100

Now with parens

```
(sweep(df, 
      STATS = as.matrix(df[rownames(df) == "Total",]),
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = "/") * 100) %>% print

           Total          A1         A2         A3         A4         A5        A6         A7
B1     65.094340  68.5499058  76.312420  63.875598  90.677966  72.065728  73.74302  20.650096
B2     32.603774  31.1989956  19.974392  33.253589   9.322034  25.469484  26.25698  73.231358
B3      2.301887   0.2510986   3.713188   2.870813   0.000000   2.464789   0.00000   6.118547
Total 100.000000 100.0000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.00000 100.000000
```

Brackets also work

```
sweep(df, 
      STATS = as.matrix(df[rownames(df) == "Total",]),
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = "/") %>% {
          round(. * 100, 2) %>% mutate_all(function(x)sprintf('%s%%',x))
    }

   Total     A1     A2     A3     A4     A5     A6     A7
1 65.09% 68.55% 76.31% 63.88% 90.68% 72.07% 73.74% 20.65%
2  32.6%  31.2% 19.97% 33.25%  9.32% 25.47% 26.26% 73.23%
3   2.3%  0.25%  3.71%  2.87%     0%  2.46%     0%  6.12%
4   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%   100%
```

Comment: Huh, how interesting. So did it think that `100` was the only input which entered the pipe, rather than the `sweep() * 100` output?

Comment: It's just order of operations - `%>%` takes precedence over `*`. See `?Syntax` for the complete list. It would also work if you used `sweep(...) %>% multiply_by(100) %>% ...` (you'd need to explicitly load `magrittr`, not just `dplyr`).